# Differences between Q and exclude in Django filter

Tags: django

I am wondering what is the exact difference between these two kinds of Django filter from performance aspects.

```
User.objects.filter(Q(first_name='R') & ~Q(last_name='Z')
```

and

```
User.objects.filter(first_name='R').exclude(last_name='Z')
```

Is there any other differences except performance?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think a good way to see if there is a difference is to compare the generated SQL code

Answer (score 3):

There is in fact no difference at all, not even performance. Both evaluate to the exact same query; they're just different ways of spelling the same thing.

Comment: Can you please prove your statement with any examples?